# Resolving power and separation of objects

Tags: optics

The resolving power of a device is its ability to differentiate two lines or points in an object, which means the higher the resolving power more will be the distance between the points. With that being said the resolving power of a microscope is given by $$R = \frac{1}{Δd}= \frac{2μ
 sinθ}{λ}$$
Question: From the equation it is clear that higher value of $Δd$ means a lower resolving power. But I think a higher value of $Δd$ mean a higher resolving power as $Δd$ is the separation between the objects(as shown in the figure). Where did I go wrong?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The greater the resolving power, $R$, the smaller the minimum distance between two objects, $\Delta d$, that can still be distinguished.

So as the resolving power increase you can distinguish objects which are closer together - it is an inverse relationship, when one goes up the other goes down.